# Best Twitter Framework for Python on App Engine?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, twitter

I'm looking to incorporate twitter API features into an app engine project that I'm working on.

I'm relatively new to both app engine and python, so I'm wondering what modules/frameworks I should use to most easily incorporate twitter, and to facilitate twitter oauth?

I've seen:
python-twitter
tipfy
gaema

Comment: I'd avoid python-twitter, it hasn't kept up with OAuth API as far as I can tell, so you'd be out of luck in a month when Twitter cuts off basic auth.  If you like it though, one option is to check out http://code.google.com/p/oauth-python-twitter2/

Answer (score 4):

I heartily recomment `tipfy`, but, as its author @moraes just said, it *is* its own, little, lightweight framework -- integration with others is possible (through WSGI middleware concepts), but your life is much simpler if you stick with a single framework, and `django` is much richer (and, of course, much bigger and less simple -- those are two sides of the same coin;-) and very very popular.

I personally like the "very lightweight" approach of tipfy (and WSGI, and Werkzeug, on which it relies), but if you have to pick one single framework for a wide variety of uses, you could surely do much worse than going with the most popular one, that is, django (e.g. as [this post](http://uswaretech.com/blog/2009/04/develop-twitter-api-application-in-django-and-deploy-on-google-app-engine/) suggests).

Answer (score 3):

[python-twitter](http://code.google.com/p/python-twitter/) is the strongest library for a do-it-yourself approach. You implement the API in your framework of choice. It is well-maintained code.

tipfy ported the TwitterMixin from Tornado, so you don't need to care about many implementation details. It is probably easier to get something done but it is integrated to tipfy, so you can't really use it as a library for other frameworks. Auth example is [here](http://tipfy-auth.appspot.com/).

gaema is also ported from Tornado, but it is unmaintained.

Theres also [tweetapp](http://github.com/tav/tweetapp), but the repository says that it is also not maintained.

Other frameworks may have similar helpers (or you can use a OAuth library).

Disclaimer: I'm author of tipfy and gaema.

Comment: I helped create tweetapp, but I second the warning, it was essentially a proof of concept we hacked together when Twitter released OAuth.  I still use parts of it in one app, but am going to use one of the others (Python Twitter Tools or tweepy maybe)

Answer (score 3):

I recommend using: Tweepy. There is an example app here: http://github.com/wasauce/tweepy-examples

Tweepy is under active development so I think it will serve you well.

Comment: Thanks for maintaining that repo. Very helpful while the Tweepy docs and official Web presence remains in limbo.

Answer (score 1):

I'm really liking [Python Twitter Tools](http://mike.verdone.ca/twitter/) but I haven't yet incorporated it into an App Engine app.  Will be soon though.  Tweepy is next on my list to checkout.